Dispatch from a controller to a controller of another Livewire component
In my project I use Laravel11 and Livewire 3. There is a push notification action that must be generated every time a specific function within Totem.php is executed, this function should generate a notification on the front. I used
$this->dispatch('ticketCreated')->to(Tickets::class);

to listen to the other controller, but it doesn't work.
This is the controller that should emit the event, I used dispatch
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Queue;
use App\Models\Ticket;

class Totem extends Component
{
...


 public function generate($queueId, $priority = false)
    {
        ...

        $this->dispatch('ticketCreated')->to(Tickets::class);

        ...
    }

 public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.totem');
    }
}

I need this event to be heard by another controller that will issue a push notification to the user, how do I make this work?

How do you listen to the event?  Please show the Tickets component. Are both components on the same page?

I listen like this in Tickets.php:
#[On('ticketCreated')]
public function updatePush()
{
$this->dispatch('ticket-Push');
}

then this second dispatch I hear on the blade tickets.blade:
**@script

the notification works when I have dispatch and a function inside Tickets, however no function there executes the push at the time I need, so it needs to be inside Totem.php

Are the components on the same page at the same time?

If you want you can edit the question and add the code inserted in the comments, so it becomes more readable

I solved the problem, I discovered that there is no way to interact between two different livewire components, only by event, but with event it did not issue my dispatch correctly, my solution was to use a new field in the database to indicate the information

If the components are present together on the same page they can communicate normally via events, otherwise not
